# What is the right formatted GridCS to request WCS from GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wcs

What is the right format to request WCS from GeoServer? The following request

[http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WCS&BOUNDINGBOX=11.25,42.1875,11.6016,42.5391,EPSG:4326&FORMAT=image/geotiff&GridBaseCRS=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326&GridCS=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326&GridOffsets=0.00137868,0.00137868&GridOrigin=11.25,42.5391&GridType=urn:ogc:def:method:WCS:1.1:2dGridIn2dCrs&IDENTIFIER=WorldDEM:World_DEM_90m&REQUEST=GetCoverage&VERSION=1.1.0&](http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WCS&BOUNDINGBOX=11.25,42.1875,11.6016,42.5391,EPSG:4326&FORMAT=image/geotiff&GridBaseCRS=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326&GridCS=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326&GridOffsets=0.00137868,0.00137868&GridOrigin=11.25,42.5391&GridType=urn:ogc:def:method:WCS:1.1:2dGridIn2dCrs&IDENTIFIER=WorldDEM:World_DEM_90m&REQUEST=GetCoverage&SERVICE=WCS&VERSION=1.1.0)

is answered by the GeoServer with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ows:ExceptionReport xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<ows:Exception locator="GridCS" exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue">
<ows:ExceptionText>Unrecognized GridCS urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

The GridCS is shown as unrecognised but is is found in the list of Capabilities.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wcs:Capabilities xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1 http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wcs/1.1.1/wcsGetCapabilities.xsd" version="1.1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" updateSequence="97" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1">
    <ows:ServiceIdentification>
        <ows:Title/>
        <ows:Abstract/>
        <ows:ServiceType>WCS</ows:ServiceType>
        <ows:ServiceTypeVersion>1.1.0</ows:ServiceTypeVersion>
        <ows:ServiceTypeVersion>1.1.1</ows:ServiceTypeVersion>
        <ows:Fees>NONE</ows:Fees>
        <ows:AccessConstraints>NONE</ows:AccessConstraints>
    </ows:ServiceIdentification>
    <ows:ServiceProvider>
        <ows:ProviderName>Some Provider</ows:ProviderName>
        <ows:ProviderSite xlink:href=""/>
        <ows:ServiceContact>
            <ows:IndividualName>Thomas Stegemann</ows:IndividualName>
            <ows:ContactInfo>
                <ows:Phone/>
                <ows:Address>
                    <ows:ElectronicMailAddress>thomas.stegemann@some.com</ows:ElectronicMailAddress>
                </ows:Address>
            </ows:ContactInfo>
        </ows:ServiceContact>
    </ows:ServiceProvider>
    <ows:OperationsMetadata>
        <ows:Operation name="GetCapabilities">
            <ows:DCP>
                <ows:HTTP>
                    <ows:Get xlink:href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wcs?"/>
                </ows:HTTP>
            </ows:DCP>
            <ows:DCP>
                <ows:HTTP>
                    <ows:Post xlink:href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wcs?"/>
                </ows:HTTP>
            </ows:DCP>
        </ows:Operation>
        <ows:Operation name="DescribeCoverage">
            <ows:DCP>
                <ows:HTTP>
                    <ows:Get xlink:href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wcs?"/>
                </ows:HTTP>
            </ows:DCP>
            <ows:DCP>
                <ows:HTTP>
                    <ows:Post xlink:href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wcs?"/>
                </ows:HTTP>
            </ows:DCP>
        </ows:Operation>
        <ows:Operation name="GetCoverage">
            <ows:DCP>
                <ows:HTTP>
                    <ows:Get xlink:href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wcs?"/>
                </ows:HTTP>
            </ows:DCP>
            <ows:DCP>
                <ows:HTTP>
                    <ows:Post xlink:href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wcs?"/>
                </ows:HTTP>
            </ows:DCP>
            <ows:Parameter name="store">
                <ows:AllowedValues>
                    <ows:Value>True</ows:Value>
                    <ows:Value>False</ows:Value>
                </ows:AllowedValues>
            </ows:Parameter>
        </ows:Operation>
        <ows:Constraint name="PostEncoding">
            <ows:AllowedValues>
                <ows:Value>XML</ows:Value>
            </ows:AllowedValues>
        </ows:Constraint>
    </ows:OperationsMetadata>
    <wcs:Contents>
        <wcs:CoverageSummary>
            <ows:Title>World DEM (90m)</ows:Title>
            <ows:Abstract>Generated from GeoTIFF</ows:Abstract>
            <ows:Keywords>
                <ows:Keyword>World_DEM_90m_16bit</ows:Keyword>
                <ows:Keyword>WCS</ows:Keyword>
                <ows:Keyword>GeoTIFF</ows:Keyword>
            </ows:Keywords>
            <ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
                <ows:LowerCorner>-180.01041653225 -89.99999999999972</ows:LowerCorner>
                <ows:UpperCorner>180.01041680108276 90.0</ows:UpperCorner>
            </ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
            <wcs:Identifier>WorldDEM:World_DEM_90m</wcs:Identifier>
        </wcs:CoverageSummary>
        <wcs:CoverageSummary>
            <ows:Title>dnb_nightshade</ows:Title>
            <ows:Abstract>Generated from GeoTIFF</ows:Abstract>
            <ows:Keywords>
                <ows:Keyword>dnb_land_ocean_ice.2012.54000x27000_geo.tiled</ows:Keyword>
                <ows:Keyword>WCS</ows:Keyword>
                <ows:Keyword>GeoTIFF</ows:Keyword>
            </ows:Keywords>
            <ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
                <ows:LowerCorner>-179.99999999999997 -90.00666691358941</ows:LowerCorner>
                <ows:UpperCorner>180.00666679012568 89.99999999999999</ows:UpperCorner>
            </ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
            <wcs:Identifier>rme:dnb_nightshade</wcs:Identifier>
        </wcs:CoverageSummary>
        <wcs:CoverageSummary>
            <ows:Title>world_250m</ows:Title>
            <ows:Abstract>Generated from ECW</ows:Abstract>
            <ows:Keywords>
                <ows:Keyword>World_250m</ows:Keyword>
                <ows:Keyword>WCS</ows:Keyword>
                <ows:Keyword>ECW</ows:Keyword>
            </ows:Keywords>
            <ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
                <ows:LowerCorner>-180.0 -89.99999999999969</ows:LowerCorner>
                <ows:UpperCorner>179.99999999999937 90.0</ows:UpperCorner>
            </ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
            <wcs:Identifier>rme:world_250m</wcs:Identifier>
        </wcs:CoverageSummary>
    </wcs:Contents>
</wcs:Capabilities>
```

Comment: I don't see it in the capabilities, can you narrow down the file you have pasted in

Comment: Do you have some very good reason to stay with WCS 1.1? Version 2.0.1 has much easier syntax.

Comment: What does a DescribeCoverage request give you for WorldDEM:World_DEM_90m

Comment: Have to stay with 1.1.0 for now

Comment: The `WGS84BoundingBox` part of the capabilities response is not telling you what CRS is supported/provided by any coverage.  It's just a hint to the client of the 2D extent of the coverages.